# Get the title of the active tab

Tags: 7

Is it possible to get the title of the currently active secondary tab?

I'd like to re-use the the title of this tab later on in the content.  I found `menu_local_tasks(1)` which comes close, but this returns full themed output.  I just want the title as I've defined it in `hook_menu()`.

**Edit:**
My `hook_menu` structure (trimmed to just the elements in ,not including sibling elements):

```
$items['events/%node'] = array(
    'title' => 'Events',
    'page callback' => 'page_events',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);

$items['events/%node/stats'] = array(
  'title' => 'Stats',
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'page callback' => 'page_stats',
  'page arguments' => array(1),
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  'weight' => 3,
);

$items['events/%node/stats/year'] = array(
  'title' => 'This Year',
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
  'weight' => 0,
);

$items['events/%node/stats/lastyear'] = array(
  'title' => 'Last Year',
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'page callback' => 'page_stats',
  'page arguments' => array(1),
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  'weight' => 1,
);
```

For example, when at the page `events/%node/stats/year`, I'd like to get `'This Year'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[menu_get_active_title()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_active_title/6) should be the function you are looking for.

```
function menu_get_active_title() {
  $active_trail = menu_get_active_trail();

  foreach (array_reverse($active_trail) as $item) {
    if (!(bool) ($item['type'] & MENU_IS_LOCAL_TASK)) {
      return $item['title'];
    }
  }
}
```

It should work for menus for which the menu type contains the flag `MENU_LOCAL_TASK` (which includes also the `MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK` menu type).

The function is also defined in Drupal 7.

**Update:** I noticed that for menus like /node/%node/view, `menu_get_active_title()` returns the title for /node/%node.
The following code should return the correct title also in those cases, including in the case the title is given by a title callback. I just tested on Drupal 7; I don't actually have Drupal 6 on the test site I use.

```
$item = end(menu_get_active_trail());

if (!empty($item['title_callback'])) {
  $args = array();
  if (!empty($item['title_arguments'])) {
    foreach ($item['title_arguments'] as $value) {
      if (is_int($value)) {
        // Get the value from the menu item map.
        if (!empty($item['map'])) {
          $args[] = $item['map'][$value];
        }
      }
      else {
        $args[] = $value;
      }
    }
  }

  $title = call_user_func_array($item['title_callback'], $args);
} 
 else {
   $title = $item['title'];
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  It returns the top level menu title.  Referencing my edit above, this function returns 'Events', when I'm looking for 'This Year'.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with [drupal_get_headers()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_get_headers/6), and then parsing through the results.

Answer (score 1):

Try **menu_get_item($path = NULL, $router_item = NULL)** http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/6. You should be able to pass the path value which will result in a returned array containing details of the menu tab entry including the 'title' value.

Use $_GET['q'] to get the current path.